# How do I make a combined object with string and image in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pygame, wxpython

I am currently trying to make a display canvas and some dynamically moving objects on the white canvas. The character should look like below:

[image: example image - character and text]

This symbolistic character should be clickable, not just the octangle but including the numeric objects around the image.

I heard about Tkinter, which is a built-in GUI library for Python, and I guess Tkinter or Pygame would be very useful to implement a character like above. But I have no idea from where I should start. Could you let me know, or at least where to start to learn how to implement a combined character such as the one above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement something like you want in this case in Tkinter, you could use the Tk `canvas`. This would let you place objects (including pictures, shapes, and text) onto it, and move them around from user-inputs, i.e. key presses or clicks on them.

There are plenty of tutorials on how to get started with `canvas` so I won't go into too much detail here. The underlying principle however would be to, after making all your objects, give them a similar tag such as `"player"`, and then interact with the `"player"` tag whenever you wish to do something with it, such as detect a click on it or move it around the canvas.

Good luck!